# How to select data from database and display it on the new row of gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to select data from database using textbox and display it on a new row of gridview. The textbox will be inputted using barcode scanner. I only need to scan the barcode and then search the data in database and add it on the new row of gridview. It will execute using ontextchange event.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub selectData(ByVal rowcount As Integer)
   sql = "Select Barcode, Name  from tbl_barcode where [Barcode] = '" + txtScanBarcode.Text + "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)   

    drDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While (drDataReader.Read())
        dtDatatable.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("Barcode", GetType([String]))) '0
        dtDatatable.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("Name", GetType([String]))) '1

        If Session("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To rowcount
                dtDatatable = DirectCast(Session("CurrentData"), DataTable)
                If dtDatatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    dr = dtDatatable.NewRow()
                    dr(0) = "Barcode"
                    dr(1) = "Name"
                End If
            Next
            dr = dtDatatable.NewRow()
            dr(0) = "Barcode"
            dr(1) = "Name"
            dtDatatable.Rows.Add(dr)
        Else
            dr = dtDatatable.NewRow()
            dr(0) = "Barcode"
            dr(1) = "Name"
            dtDatatable.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If


    End While
      If Session("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
        dtDatatable.Load(drDataReader)
        GridView1.DataSource = DirectCast(Session("CurrentData"), DataTable)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
          dtDatatable.Load(drDataReader)
        GridView1.DataSource = dtDatatable
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
     Session("CurrentData") = dtDatatable

End Sub

Protected Sub txtScanBarcode_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtScanBarcode.TextChanged

      If Session("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(Session("CurrentData"), DataTable)
        Dim count As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
        selectData(count)
      Else
        selectData(1)
      End If
End Sub
```

The above code, able to add new row but can't take the data from database. When I execute it, and scanned a barcode, it doesn't display the data from database, it add text 'Barcode' on dr(0) and text 'name' on dr(1)  instead. So, I think the sql for taking the data from database isn't working. it doesn't call any data from database.
do you have any suggestion, how to select data from database and fetch it into row?

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate the though.

Comment: you may want to look into parameters for your query.

Comment: Thanks Ben. do you some link or source about how to use parameter on my problem?

Comment: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use reader, use instead DataSet then get Data on it

```
Public Function getDataInDB(ByVal sQuery As String) As String
    getDataInDB = Nothing
    Try
        CMD = New SqlCommand(sQuery, TestResult)
        Dim sqlAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dataS As DataSet
        sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
        dataS = New DataSet
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataS, "getRecord")
        getDataInDB = dataS.Tables("getRecord").Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

By not using reader it will be more safe and fast to get a data like this...

Comment: would you mind to guide me using your suggestion. to be honest, I don't know how to use and call function. it's new for me. I'm sorry...
I added the sql inside try and change the "getRecord" into "Barcode"... Then how can I set it into gridview?

Comment: My code is just to get a Single data you need like:

Dim Barcode As String = getDataInDB("SELECT SOMETHING THAT I WANT TO GET")

Output: Barcode is USBN00000001 Then you can add it to your new datagridview including your some datas

Comment: Dear Vipa,,, I tried your suggestion. it is something like this: Private Sub selectData2()
sql = getDataInDB("Select Barcode, Name  from tbl_barcode where [Barcode] = '" + txtScanBarcode.Text + "'")
        GridView1.DataSource = sql
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
and then I call selectdata2() on ontextchange event... but it say 'A field or property with the name 'Barcode' was not found on the selected data source'. am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Do you want display the result in DataGridView in (Databind) or just fetch the result on a variable ?

Comment: I want to display the result in gridview... for example: I scan 001 on txtscan barcode... then it will display the name and barcode 001... then I scan again on txtscan barcode 002, it will display on the next row after 001....
something like this:
Barcode  Name
001       one
002       two
....etc

Comment: Thanks Vipa. I get it what you mean.... I implement your code and call it using my code above... Then its work... sorry for the late understanding.... and Thank you very much....

Comment: Ohhh, sorry bro for the late replay too i'm a bit bz yesterday but i'm happy that you get it =D, are you a test software developer too ?

Comment: I am still a college student doing an internship. this is part of the project that given to me...

Comment: Ohhh,, thats a very good practice, you will be able to master it before going to industry anyway thats again for the question and a little chitchat...

Comment: Dear, Vipa... sorry, may I ask another question. do you know how to remove / highlight the duplicate value in gridview? I already post it in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050326/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicates-values-in-gridview
if you have any suggestion, please let me know. Thank you.