# how to find and remove duplicates values in gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am working on barcode project. I can add the scanned barcode into gridview list, but I found some problem with removing the duplicates barcode scanned. so whenever the barcode scanned it will add to the list even for the barcode that already in the list. I want it to highlight it so that the user know which barcode was duplicated or even remove it. the data on gridview was take from a database based on barcode.

example table data:

```
 Barcode |  Items   |
 001     |  one     |  --> this will be red
 002     |  two     |        
 002     |  two     |  --> this will be red
 001     |  one     | --> this will be red
```

Here is my code :

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As GridView, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
  Dim oldvalue, newvalue As String
    oldvalue = String.Empty
    newvalue = String.Empty
    For j As Integer = 0 To j < 2 Step 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To i < GridView1.Rows.Count Step 1
            oldvalue = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text
            If oldvalue = newvalue Then
                GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text = String.Empty
            End If
            newvalue = oldvalue
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

but it doesn't seem to work... it doesn't change anything... the duplicate still display.

I even found this that can be change the color of duplicate into RED, and change it a bit because it's only detect the previous index, but still the same....

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As GridView, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
       If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim idxPrev As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex - 1
            If 1 <= e.Row.RowIndex Then
                If e.Row.Cells(3).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(3).Text Then
                    e.Row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                    sender.Rows(idxPrev).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

this code only able to display something like this:

```
 Barcode |  Items   |
 001     |  one     |  --> this will be red
 001     |  one     |   --> this will be red     
 002     |  two     |  
 001     |  one     |
```

The expected result:

```
 Barcode |  Items   |
 001     |  one     |  
 002     |  two     |
```

Or highlight the duplicate text.

I don't know what was wrong on my code.

Thanks in advances.... I really appreciate the though..

Comment: did you use the break point to check at which line the code stops ? does it go through this line `If e.Row.Cells(3).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(3).Text` ? if yes, are the values alright ?

Comment: the code doesn't loop for each value on gridview... it's only check the previous one index from current index. that line working but the loop is not working.

Comment: you don't need to use a loop inside the GridView1_RowDataBound event, because RowDataBound itself it works like a loop through your gridview rows, so you just need to check the value and remove or highlight it whenever it's duplicated

Answer (score 0):

> Algorithm: Remove duplicate data
>
> Step 1: Store the first row's , first cells content
>
> Step 2: Loop through the entire grid from the 2nd row till the end 
>             and check if the Name column's value is same or not.
>       If it is same, then replace the value with empty string 
>       else continue with the new value. The above process will repeat itself.

```
//Step 1:
Dim oldvalue As String
oldvalue = String.Empty
If GridView1.Rows.Count>0 then
   string oldvalue = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;

   //Step 2:
   For i As Integer = 1 To i < GridView1.Rows.Count Step 1
       If oldvalue = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text Then
          GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text = String.Empty
          GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text = String.Empty
       Else
          oldvalue=GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text
       End If
   Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan. I tried your suggestion. but it shows an error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." .... in this code :  oldvalue = GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text

Comment: Hmmm... Do you have a database wherein you store all the Barcode value ? or you just want to check all datas within the DataGridView ?

Comment: I have the database, then select data from database using textbox  and add it into gridview one by one. the data will be added each enter.

Comment: you have atleast one row in grid or not? Ok. i will change the code little bit try it.

Comment: Thank you Kumar,,, I really appreciate it. the code ealready works, but it still able to add the duplicate value....